# How to set SoapAction with SoapJaxbDataFormat

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-camel

Hi I am trying to use Camel-SOAP component to create the soap message to invoke a .Net SOAP 1.2 service.
It is not working beacause the the SoapJaxbDataFormat is not putting the SOAP action, I am able to test and call the service using SOAPUI and I see in the request generated by SOAPUI that the soap header with action is filled in.
How can get action filled in ?

```
        SoapJaxbDataFormat soapDF = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("xx.zzz.yy", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(DpoService.class, true));
    soapDF.setVersion("1.2");
    soapDF.setNamespacePrefixRef(NAMESPACE_MAPPING_BEAN_NAME);

    from("direct:quote")
            .marshal(soapDF)
            .log("${body}")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=\"http://example.com/services/DpoServiceContract/GetPof\""))
            .to("http://localhost:7898/DpoService.svc");
```

The reason I am using this approach is because the CFX and WSImport generated client code does not work.
I was able to call the service using a velocity template to generate the SOAP msg.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the SOAP action from your message header, just like this:

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.SOAP_ACTION, "SOAPACTION");
```

Comment: Thank you. this is great help.